# Kinetic energy, beginner question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

so if 1J is equivalent to the kinetic energy of a 2kg-mass moving at 1m/s,

and 1kcal (4184J) is the energy needed to heat 1l of water up by one degree celsius,

then 1kcal is equivalent to the kinetic energy of a 2kg-mass movingt at 64m/s?

I hope this is wrong, and if so, please tell me why, because intuitively it seems to me that the kinetic energy of a 2kg-mass moving at 64m/s should be much greater than the energy needed to heat up a liter of water by one degree celsius.

Comment: Its not wrong. But they are both different kinds of energy, one is potential energy due to change in temperature (heating water), while the other is Kinetic Energy (Energy of Motion).
Bigger the mass, higher the energy requirement to change its temperature.

You can imagine it like this - if a 2 kg mass moving with 64m/s hits water (1 dm3 = 1L) and comes to rest and losing all its KE to heat the water, the temperature of water will change by 1K or 1°C.

Comment: Hello, @Ashutosh! Please don't use comments to answer the question, but instead use comments to clarify and improve the question. If you'd like to post a brief answer, please post an answer.

Comment: Thank you, anyway, Ashutosh

Comment: sorry @rob I was unaware of the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is correct.  The two have equivalent energies.

> intuitively it seems to me that the kinetic energy of a 2kg-mass moving at 64m/s should be much greater than the energy needed to heat up a liter of water by one degree celsius.

Neither of those things seem to be in my daily experience, so I'm not able to easily compare either one.   But water has a fairly large heat capacity.  I suspect that if you tried to heat a (well-insulated) liter of water with an egg-beater or something similar, you would find that it heats quite slowly compared to the effort that you produce.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I guess that's one of the purposes of science, correcting intuitions.